# Auto Decrement Cascading Primary Key

Tags: mysql

I am taking data that has an id in the 200,000 -500,000 range and trying to convert it to demo data. I want to put it at the beginning of the database rather than in the middle. The ids are not consecutive, there are gaps in the incrementing because of other data that was removed.

I tried using this command

```
UPDATE table_name SET `id`=(`id`-200000)
```

It did a great job for the first group, but there is only about 1000 records total and I still have stuff up in the 200,000 range. I stupidly thought I could run it again, but once it tried assigning a number's id to negative 1, it gave me an unsigned key error.

I would normally just remove the primary key from the insert statement and reinsert it into a new DB, but in this case there are multiple other tables that have foreign key constraints that auto cascade to keep it all in sync.

Anybody have a useful script handy that could accomplish a task like this? I am not sure how often this situation comes up, but hoping someone has solved it.

### update

I tried making a stored procedure (my first), but getting an error: `unknown system variable 'id'`

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_demo_decrement;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_demo_decrement()
BEGIN
  DECLARE lastId INT DEFAULT 5;
  demo_loop : LOOP
    SET id = lastId +1;
        SET lastId = id;
    SELECT id; 
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Comment: What`s your table definition?

Comment: Does it really matter what the definition is since I am only trying to change a single `int` field?  Trying to adapt this script to see if it will work. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105933/38071

Comment: It does matter, since based on your error, it sounds like you have an unsigned int as your PK, which is why you can't have negative numbers

Comment: But what I really need is a while loop that loops through each item reducing the number to the last id+1, I don't need negative values

Comment: Check modified post

Comment: in the procedure it looks like you don't declare a variable called `id`. Did you mean this to be your column name? If so you need to write a query against the particular table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned some new tricks tonight, here is the stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_demo_front_load;
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_demo_front_load()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a,b INT DEFAULT 4;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id  FROM client ORDER BY id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO b;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
        UPDATE client SET id = a + 1 where id = b;
        SET a = a+1;

END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END;
```